# why does my dojo heading overlay my roundRectList?

Tags: dojo, css-position, dojox.mobile

I generate a scrollableview with a heading and a roundrectList inside. Everything works great but the heading is not fixed so i replace the addchild for the heading with a addFixedBar. Now the heading is fixed but it overlays the RoundRectList. The list has its upper end beound the heading and i cant read it.
How do i tell the list to be smaller?

```
if (parentNodeId !== previousParentNodeId){
        var newDiv = new dojox.mobile.ScrollableView({
                    id: divNodesId,
                    dojoType: "dojox.mobile.ScrollableView",
                    scrollDir: "v",
                    style: "background-color: #d0d0d0"
        });
        newDiv.placeAt('mobileView','first');

        //look if there is a previous parent, only if there is one generate back button; needed for root div
        if (previousParentNodeId == null){
            var newHeading = new dojox.mobile.Heading({
                        id: h1NodesId,
                        dojoType: "dojox.mobile.Heading",
                        fixed: "top",
                        label: "Knoten&uuml;bersicht"
            });
        }
        else {//create heading with back button
                        var newHeading = new dojox.mobile.Heading({
                        id: h1NodesId,
                        dojoType: "dojox.mobile.Heading",
                        back: "zur&uuml;ck",
                        moveTo: previousParentNode,
                        fixed: "top",
                        label: divNodeLabel
            });
        }

        //newHeading.placeAt(divNodesId,'first');
        newDiv.addFixedBar(newHeading);
        newHeading.startup();

        ulNodesId = "ulNodes"+parentNodeId;
        var newUl = new dojox.mobile.RoundRectList({
                    id: ulNodesId,
                    dojoType: "dojox.mobile.RoundRectList"
        });
        newUl.placeAt(divNodesId,'last');
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding css style property directly to the  tag for RoundRectList

For example:

```
<div id="divNodesId" style="z-index: 1;position: relative;top: 15px;"></div>
```

You could also try adding the same style to:

```
    var newUl = new dojox.mobile.RoundRectList({
                id: ulNodesId,
                dojoType: "dojox.mobile.RoundRectList",
                style: "z-index: 1;position: relative;top: 15px;"
    });
```

Use css position to move it around or just z-index to see it.

Maybe try adding width and height css to get what you want??:

```
    var newDiv = new dojox.mobile.ScrollableView({
                id: divNodesId,
                dojoType: "dojox.mobile.ScrollableView",
                scrollDir: "v",
                style: "width: 800px,height: 90px;background-color: #d0d0d0"
    });
```

You can also user css left,right,bottom too.  Use + or - px number to find the position you want.  Not sure how to make the list smaller though, you might not need to with the css stuff above. Hard to tell without a full example..

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of things to change in your code, including:

- Add a call of the startup() method of the ScrollableView (placed
  after the addition of the view to the DOM).
- For adding the RoundRectList to the ScrollableView, use for instance newUl.placeAt(newDiv.containerNode); (I use the names of your variables which hold the instances of RoundRectList and respectively ScrollableView. Note that the list is added to ScrollableView's containerNode).
- Remove the dojoType constructor argument (this is not for
  programmatic instanciation).

The easiest would be that you take inspiration or compare your code with dojox/mobile/tests/test_dynamic-ScrollableView-vh-vf.html (that you can find the the source distribution). This test does exactly what you want to achieve.